# Hardware solution to bridge EAP AKA to WPA-Personal

Tags: wireless-networking, wpa

I am not sure if bridging is the correct term for my problem but here it is.

In my residence we have an EAP AKA (WPA-Enterprise) Wi-Fi network requiring username and password to be entered in order to get access.

Following some guides I managed to access it from Windows 10 and Android mobile phones, where it is available the option AKA under EAP giving you the option to enter username and password.

The same functionality is not available though on all devices (namely some Smart TV OSs and funny enough also an Android TV box), either because EAP is not available, less frequent, or because choosing the network it allows to enter only a password but not the username.

As a general solution, I was considering the option of an hardware solution to connect to the EAP AKA Wi-Fi network and create a WPA-Personal Wi-Fi network to connect all home devices.

So far, I have been looking at some "out-of-the-box" solutions to accomplish this but found none. Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's EAP-AKA? AFAIK that's usually based on keys held in a SIM card and does not involve passwords; PEAP or TTLS are the common username/password-based methods.

Comment: On the guide to connect to this network on Android, it says to choose as EAP Method AKA. To be fair on the similar guides for iOS, Windows Phone and Win 10, there is no reference to it, so I am wondering if it is just a trick for Android while the network is technically different.